Missing "./connectors/injected" specifier in "@wagmi/core" package
I'm encountering an issue during the build process of my Vite project. The error message I'm getting is as follows:
[vite-plugin-pwa:build] Missing "./connectors/injected" specifier in "@wagmi/core" package
error during build:
Error: Missing "./connectors/injected" specifier in "@wagmi/core" package
at e (file:///C:/Users/pierr/Desktop/stratus/Amelie/brand-app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-df561101.js:21420:25)
at n (file:///C:/Users/pierr/Desktop/stratus/Amelie/brand-app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-df561101.js:21420:627)
at o (file:///C:/Users/pierr/Desktop/stratus/Amelie/brand-app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-df561101.js:21420:1297)
at resolveExportsOrImports (file:///C:/Users/pierr/Desktop/stratus/Amelie/brand-app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-df561101.js:28712:20)
at resolveDeepImport (file:///C:/Users/pierr/Desktop/stratus/Amelie/brand-app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-df561101.js:28731:31)
at tryNodeResolve (file:///C:/Users/pierr/Desktop/stratus/Amelie/brand-app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-df561101.js:28419:20)
at Object.resolveId (file:///C:/Users/pierr/Desktop/stratus/Amelie/brand-app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-df561101.js:28180:28)
at file:///C:/Users/pierr/Desktop/stratus/Amelie/brand-app/node_modules/vite/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:25544:40
at async PluginDriver.hookFirstAndGetPlugin (file:///C:/Users/pierr/Desktop/stratus/Amelie/brand-app/node_modules/vite/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:25444:28)
at async resolveId (file:///C:/Users/pierr/Desktop/stratus/Amelie/brand-app/node_modules/vite/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:24117:26)
Has anyone encountered a similar issue or have any suggestions on how to resolve this?
Thank you in advance for your help!
I have tried the following steps to resolve the issue:
Verified the version of @wagmi/core in package.json.
Updated all dependencies using npm update @wagmi/core.
Checked the import path in my code:
import { InjectedConnector } from '@wagmi/core/connectors/injected';
Ensured the module exists in node_modules/@wagmi/core/connectors.
Deleted node_modules and package-lock.json, then reinstalled dependencies with npm install.
I was expecting these steps to resolve the missing module error and allow the build process to complete successfully. However, the error persists, and I'm unable to use the latest version of @wagmi/core in my Vite project.
I would like to be able to use the latest version of @wagmi/core without encountering this error.
Thank you for your assistance!
